# How to store multiple related time series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, quantitative-finance

I'm new to Pandas and would like some insight from the pros. I need to perform various statistical analyses (multiple regression, correlation etc) on >30 time series of financial securities' daily Open, High, Low, Close prices. Each series has 500-1500 days of data. As each analysis looks at multiple securities, I'm wondering if it's preferable from an ease of use and efficiency perspective to store each time series in a separate df, each with date as the index, or to merge them all into a single df with a single date index, which would effectively be a 3d df. If the latter, any recommendations on how to structure it?

Any thoughts much appreciated.

PS. I'm working my way up to working with intraday data across multiple timezones but that's a bit much for my first pandas project; this is a first step in that direction.

Comment: how did this work out for you? I am thinking of doing this, but I have 200,000 time series!

Comment: Thanks Caroline and acushner for the suggestions. Seems there's no absolute consensus so I'll try both on for size and come back again later.

Answer (score 3):

since you're only dealing with OHLC, it's not that much data to process, so that's good.

for these types of things i usually use a multiindex (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html) with symbol as the first level and date as the second. then you can have just the columns OHLC and you're all set.

to access multiindex use the `.xs` function.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are going to correlate everything with everything, my suggestion is to put this into separate dataframes and put them all in a dictionary, ie {"Timeseries1":df1, "Timeseries 2":df2...}. Then, when you want to correlate some timeseries together, you can merge them and put suffixes in the columns of every different df to differentiate between them.

Probably you are interested in this talk [Python for Financial Data Analysis with pandas](https://wesmckinney.com/blog/python-for-financial-data-analysis-with-pandas/) by the author of pandas himself.

Comment: Thanks. What would the advantage be of keeping them separate but in a dictionary and then merging them later, as opposed to just merging everything at once to start with?
Thanks for the link - I watched that and his 10 minute pandas intro video.

Comment: My line of thinking is that the 30 time series are not a single entity (such is my assumption). The OHLC time series is a single entity. So it makes more sense to write a codebase which has functions like:
correlate(df1,df2) than corelate(merged_df_where_i_need_to_remember_to_slice_it_and_take_the_first_two). But, if you want to do all the operations at once for all 30 series, then investing in designing a multiindexed data structure is probably best, although it is harder to master for a beginner.

Comment: What would you do if you had 200,000+ Series? I wont be correlating them, but I do want to try to cluster them, so I need to manipulate them all together...

Comment: A related question. If I put each series in a separate df, presumably I will need to provide it with its own unique variable name? I'll be reading the series in off the web - is there a trick for giving them each a unique variable name without having to manually specify names like df1, df2 etc? Or would I end up needing to put them into an array or other structure so I could just index them?
For example if at runtime the user chooses to download VIX, SPX, and F, the code will go fetch those series. Is there a way to dynamically create variable names dfVIX, dfSPX (or df1, df2) etc? Thanks!

Comment: well, a straightforward way is to create a dictionary of those, like: {"VIX":fetched_df1, "SPX":fetched_df2}